# How to identify each pc as unique connected with same ip address in php

Tags: php

I am struggling to find out a way in php to identify each pc as a unique pc that are connected with same ip address.i am making a visitor statistics plugin everything working fine but when 4-5 pc browse my site with same ip it shows only one visitor online because of same ip.i could not figure out how to overcome this.
please anyone help.
thank you

Comment: What about cookies?

Comment: pollute their box with [Evercookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evercookie)

Comment: if i set cookie and save value to database then every pc will be same value. suppose value="value" then setcookie("name","value"). value will be save in database.then how can i track that this value is that pc cookie.@PaulSpiegel

Comment: What about session id? :-)

Comment: i m now using uniqueid of session but i do not know when exactly it expire ? @PaulSpiegel

Comment: You can find everything you need in the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php - php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php - I would probably look for a OO-library if you do not already use a framework.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['tracking_id'])) {
    $trackingId = $_COOKIE['tracking_id'];
} else {
    $trackingId = uniqid();
}
$expire = strtotime('+30 days');
$path = '/';
setcookie('tracking_id', $trackingId, $expire, $path);
// log using $trackingId
```

Note that `$trackingId` identifies a browser - not a PC. If a user changes the browser or another user logs in on the PC you will get a new ID.

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to get a MAC address of a machine that's in a separate network from the server.

I would avoid tracking session variables, mainly because I would not want to take the chance that the session variable gets captured and used for session spoofing.

I would suggest generating a cookie with a unique variable for each machine. (What that function would be is up to you.) Track IP address plus cookie variable to follow unique machines.

Comment: How to do that.how to generate for each pc.the plugin will be add to a website when a user visit the site it will count as unique pc. @Roberto